# Edit one page of a TIFF PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have a multipage TIFF file: how could I edit the second page of it using PIL without disturbing or having to rewrite the other pages? I can install a Python library, but I would prefer as few added as possible.

I have looked at both [`.seek`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.seek) and [`ImageSequence.Iterator`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagesequence.htm), but neither seem to let me edit in place; rather, they just let you treat the multi-page TIFF as lots of unrelated one-page TIFFs.

Comment: If the pages are compressed, then editing them will change their size. Since TIFF files use absolute offsets for the data links, you will need to rewrite the entire file if you modify a single page.

Comment: @BitBank I don't think the files ate compressed but either way, the difficulty in coming up with is splitting and then recombining in a memory efficient way with the least number of file. Or somehow just feels wrong to me to split a hundred page tiff into separate files, change one page and then convert them all back

Comment: If it helps, my problem is very similar tohttp://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23965 but with pil

Comment: I can't speak about other imaging libraries because I wrote my own to handle such tasks. If your pages are uncompressed, then it is pretty simple to modify a single page of the file without having to read/re-write everything. The only thing you need to do is traverse the links to get to the start of the page you're interested in. Once there, you can read it and write back the data at that spot without touching the rest.

Comment: @BitBank If you want the rep, you can answer that. Otherwise, I found a way to do it with imagemagick